# My two div's won't stack next to each other

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have two divs, wrapped inside a bigger div. I need to stack them next to each other rather than have them display as blocks that they typically do. I followed suggestions on similar stackoverflow questions and floated the first inner div to the left and floated the 2nd inner div to the right. No success.

I floated both inner div's to left and set overflow:hidden to the wrapper div. No success. I also, set both the inner div display's to an inline-block type. No success. They all stack over each other and this is not what I want.

Here is the semantic markup along with the CSS:

```
<div align="left" style="border:2px dotted #fff;margin-top:5px;">
           <!--  <span class="hyperlink_message">This is the message, redundant</span>      -->
                <div class="hyperlink preview" style=";padding-top:8px;border:1px solid #bbc5ee;">  
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/parijat" target="_blank">
                            <img src="https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/395790_10150612393596211_887151733_n.jpg" alt="image not found" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:solid 1px gray;margin-right:5px;" ></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <div style="font-size:12px;color:black;"><a href="{$hyperlinktext[i].url}"><b>My Facebook page</b></a></div>
                        <div style="font-size:10px;color:gray;">www.facebook.com</div>
                        <div style="padding-top:5px;font-size:10px;color:gray;">Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div> 
                </div>
</div>
```

(please excuse the CSS styles included along with the markup, dabbling with some terrible legacy code at the moment.

And the corresponding JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hpTym/

What do you guys think is going wrong here?

Comment: inline css D: I dont even want to touch this

Comment: LOL! sorry, legacy code :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for the floating divs, or do you need them to float without specific width?